# Adding Number Seperator to an Expression having operator and functions in java

Tags: java, string

I have a math expression string
i.e `String exp = "1890+8591-10000"`
I just made simple exp for example.
The result of string when added number Seperator should be `"1,890+8,591-10,000"`.

I tried using Decimalformatter but it didn't work for above example.
Decimalformatter work for only the string having numbers only.

I think you got my problem.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us your code for parsing that expression without separators. Basically, show us the code where you parse the numbers, and then show us how you changed that code when trying to use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). --- Right now, this question reads like a write-my-code-for-me request, and that's not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: You should parse out the numbers, format each of them individually, then put the string back together again.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the characters while:

- Printing any char that is not a digit.
- Buffering the digits then format and print them when you passed them.

Code:

```
String s = "1890+8591-10000";
NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        strBuilder.append(c);
    } else {
        if(strBuilder.length() > 0){
            System.out.print(myFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(strBuilder.toString())));
            strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        }

        System.out.print(c);
    }
}

if(strBuilder.length() > 0){
    System.out.print(myFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(strBuilder.toString())));
}
```

Output:

```
1,890+8,591-10,000
```